# How to get a count of sequences used in a range in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with a series of varchars, for example:

```
0001
0002
0003
0007
0008
0010
0012
0013
0014
0015
```

I want to get a count of how many consecutive numbers were used in a range. For example:

```
RangeStart    RangeEnd    Count
0001          0003            3
0007          0008            2
0010          0010            1
0012          0015            4
```

How could I accomplish this with a SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work if you only have numbers as values.

```
declare @T table(Col char(4))
insert into @T values
('0001'),
('0002'),
('0003'),
('0007'),
('0008'),
('0010'),
('0012'),
('0013'),
('0014'),
('0015')

;with C as
(
  select Col,
         Col - row_number() over(order by Col) as grp
  from @T
)
select min(Col) as RangeStart,
       max(Col) as RangeEnd,
       count(*) as [Count]
from C
group by grp
```

Comment: Really nice, works perfectly. I am not too familiar with CTE and is something I should probably get used to. On a side note, how would I modify this query if I need to convert the field first. For example, instead of '0001' I have 'Num-0001', so I have to do CONVERT(INT,RIGHT(Col,4)) first?

Comment: @esac That would work just fine. BTW, the CTE is not really necessary here. You could use a sub query as well.

Answer (score -1):

IMO, I don't think this is something that SQL is going to be very good at.  I would do this using code, or if it must be in the database using a .Net stored procedure.